# Controlling mode of operation for TDA8948J audio amplifier

Tags: amplifier, audio, schematics

This is exceprt of an audio amplifier schematic powered by the TDA8948J. It has three modes of operation which are controlled by applying the proper DC voltage on pin 10 (MODE1):

- STANDBY: less than 0.8 V
- MUTE: between 4.5 V and 15 V
- ON: between 16V and 18V

I am having a hard time understanding how this is implemented in the circuit below. **What kind of voltages do I need to apply to the inputs (marked red) in order to turn the amplifier on? What about mute?**
I tried applying VCC (18V) directly to pin 10 (MODE) which does work - it turns the amplifier on, sound is on.
However, applying 5V to MUTE and STANDBY pins didn't work, which was a random guess anyways. How is the bottom part (STANDBY, MODE, 22V) related to the upper part?

[image: Audio amplifier schematic excerpt]

Comment: What does the data sheet tell you?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? The TDA8948J datasheet tells about MODE1 pin operation, but not about the surrounding circuitry

Comment: Does it tell you voltage levels on the pins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered same problem with my Philips Micro Theater MCD122 which use same audio amp IC. My problem was intermittent sound from left or right speaker randomly.
When I check Mode voltage it was around 4.5 V which could not turn on the IC.
Later I found that Q5 was faulty (Collector and Emitter always short). It is OK now after replacing Q5 with similar smd NPN transistor. However, the voltage level for Muting is not correct as per IC's datasheet. But it's working fine now. I have made a simplified drawing to understand easily.

[image: TDA8948J Mode1 control]